# IPhone application view transition becomes jerky

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance

I have a view containing a UITableView using prototype cells. It contains a few labels I have connected to a subclassed UITableViewCell in interface builder.

When I click a row, I have created a segue in a storyboard to a detail view. This view can also be accessed via a segue from another class.

My table and detail views use a navigation controller.

My problem is that when I transition from the table view to the detail view and back again multiple times, I've noticed that after a while the transition from the detail view back to the table view starts getting jerky. The table scrolling begins to be slightly jerky too.

I'm using ARC.

If anyone can give me tips on what is likely to cause this, or tools I should use to investigate it would be really appreciated.

I'll put down some of my source code in case that helps. Please let me know if there's anything else I should provide.

The table view is populated from a remote service, however the problem occurs after the table is already populated and I'm not calling the service again.

Table view header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SearchManager.h"

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, FreeTextSearchClient>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *TableView;

@end
```

Table view code:

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "SearchManager.h"
#import "LocationTableViewCell.h"
#import "StarRatingDisplay.h"
#import "LocationViewController.h"


@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

@synthesize TableView;

SearchManager *searchManager;
NSArray *locations;
bool isSearching = false;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //hide nav bar
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true];

    //deselect cell
    NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [self.TableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.TableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath animated:false];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    searchManager = [[SearchManager alloc] initWithFreeTextClient:self]; 
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"LocationDetails"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        LocationViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.TableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        vc.location = [locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}

- (void)showStarRating:(LocationTableViewCell*) cell: (float) score {

    int x = cell.titleLabel.frame.origin.x;
    int y = cell.ratingLabel.frame.origin.y + 2;

    //add rating
    NSArray *stars = [StarRatingDisplay GetTinyStarsForScore:score];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [stars objectEnumerator];
    UIImage *thisStar;
    int i = 0;


    //create image views for stars and place them on the callout
    while(thisStar = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thisStar];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(x+(thisStar.size.width + 2)*i, y, thisStar.size.width, thisStar.size.height);            

        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];

        i++;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableView 

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if([locations count] == 0 && isSearching) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return [locations count];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if ([locations count] == 0) {
        return 53;
    } else {
        return 77;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([locations count] > 0) {
        LocationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

        Location *location = [locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.titleLabel.text = location.Name;
        cell.addressLabel.text = location.Address.description;
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d rating%@", location.Ratings, (location.Ratings != 1 ? @"s" : @"")];
        [self showStarRating:cell :location.Score];

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        //if there are no locations, show the no results cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NoResults"];
        return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if(searchBar.text.length > 0) {
        [searchManager FreeTextSearch:searchBar.text];
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        isSearching = true;
    }
}

- (void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //clear search and remove keyboard
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    isSearching = false;
}

#pragma mark - SearchClient delegate

- (void) ReceiveTextSearchResponse:(NSArray *) response {
    NSLog(@"Response received");
    locations = response;
    [self.TableView reloadData];
} 


@end
```

Table cell header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol RatingTableViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required

- (void) changeCommentCellHeight:(int) height;
- (void) setEditingOffset;
- (void) removeEditingOffset;

@end
```

Table cell:

```
@interface RatingTableCellViewController : UITableViewCell <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <RatingTableViewDelegate> tableViewDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) bool hasRating;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float rating;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *yourRatingLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *star1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *star2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *star3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *star4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *star5;

- (IBAction) submitClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) cancelClicked:(id)sender;
- (void) openCell;
- (void) closeCell;
- (void) cancelRating;

@end
```

Detail view header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Location.h"
#import "RatingTableCellViewController.h"

@interface LocationViewController : UITableViewController <RatingTableViewDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) Location *location;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *averageRatingCell;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet RatingTableCellViewController *yourRatingCell;


@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ratingLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *address;

@end
```

Detail View:

```
#import "LocationViewController.h"
#import "StarRatingDisplay.h"
#import "RatingViewController.h"
#import "RatingTableCellViewController.h"

@interface LocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation LocationViewController

@synthesize location;

@synthesize averageRatingCell, yourRatingCell;
@synthesize ratingLabel;
@synthesize address;

int commentCellHeight = 45;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self showStarRating:averageRatingCell];
    ratingLabel.Text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d Rating%@:", location.Ratings, location.Ratings != 1 ? @"s" : @""];

    self.navigationItem.title = location.Name;

    address.text = location.Address.description;
    address.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    address.numberOfLines = 5;

    yourRatingCell.tableViewDelegate = self;

    // Show the nav bar. It might be hidden if coming from search view.
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:false];


}

- (void) setEditingOffset {
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 60)];
}

- (void) removeEditingOffset {
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        return commentCellHeight;
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 70;
    }
    return 45;
}

- (void) changeCommentCellHeight:(int) height {
    commentCellHeight = height;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}


- (void)showStarRating:(UITableViewCell*) cell {

    int x = 132;
    int y = 12;

    //add rating
    NSArray *stars = [StarRatingDisplay GetStarsForScore:location.Score];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [stars objectEnumerator];
    UIImage *thisStar;
    int i = 0;


    //create image views for stars and place them on the callout
    while(thisStar = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thisStar];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(x+(thisStar.size.width + 2)*i, y, thisStar.size.width, thisStar.size.height);            

        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];

        i++;
    }
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //reset the comment/rating cell height
    NSIndexPath *commentPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection: 0];
    RatingTableCellViewController *ratingCell = (RatingTableCellViewController*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:commentPath];
    [ratingCell cancelRating];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}




@end
```